# How does tex1DGrad work in cuda? Will it give gradient of the function?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to retrieve the gradient of a buffer in the texture memory. Right now I implemented it using two `tex1D()`. Is it possible just using `tex1DGrad` to directly get the value with just one texture fetch?

Comment: CUDA: [tex1DGrad()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#tex1dgrad-object). HLSL analog: [tex1DGrad()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I will still use my old way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. `tex1Dgrad` doesn't calculate a gradient. It performs a conventional texture fetch, but uses a programmer supplied gradient as an input to select the level of detail from a [mipmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) texture.